# Getting response null while testing TCP calls for multiple api with JMeter using CSV Data Config

Tags: tcp, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I am trying to load test with Jmeter using TCP sampler with CSV DATA config. When I am running a single API(TCP call)in the loop then it is getting the response of all API request, however, if I am hitting two different API calls(TCP calls) in the loop the second one always fails with response null, but I do see the server responding when I test the same using command line. What could be the cause and possible solution to help Jmeter read the response for all API requests is made.

Success case with only one TCP calls:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4Hhr.png)

Failure case with 2 different TCP calls:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKbJ7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the in Jmeter it reads the one CSV file in one user thread. Though in the same test plan I have two TCP sampler test cases and both were reading different CSV files using CSV data config but the file in the first test case was getting read and the second test case CSV file was ignored. That is why the second test case was failing. So this infers that to run multiple test cases in a test plan we can read only one file at the test plan level.